# Android : send sms with images (more smileys)

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to send messages (Wishes) from my application to my friends and I want more images (Templates) to be added into the text message as like smileys.

Is there any possible solutions to do this? I don't want the MMS to be used to send the greetings like images.

Comment: The display of smiley images is a function of the receiving app; i.e., the image is not actually embedded in the message. The app will search the incoming text message and replace the smileys with its own local images as needed. The only way to simulate this functionality would be to write the receiving app to recognize certain strings that you define as representing the images you wish to display upon receipt.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527536/android-send-mms-message-with-picture-on-sdcard)

Comment: @user3355820 I dont the default MSG ox to open to choose contacts .. I have all contacts with my application (user) and will send messages from service (Background)..